# How to change the display every hour in Swift UI like the Starbucks Coffee app

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

[*enter image description here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMcxa.png)

I want the Swift UI to display in the Navigation View at specified times like the Starbucks app ("good morning" at 5:00, "good afternoon" at 12:00, "good night" at 17:00). please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare current time with the time you have set for each title to achieve what you're looking for

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var navigationTitle = ""
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{    
            }//: VSTACK
            .navigationTitle(navigationTitle) //TITLE
        }//: NAVIGATION
        .onAppear {
            let morningTime = "05:00:00"
            let noonTime = "12:00:00"
            let nightTime = "17:00:00"
            //DateFormatter
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            let currentTime = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
            //Conditions to compare time
            if currentTime >= morningTime && currentTime < noonTime{
                navigationTitle = "Good Morning"
            }else if currentTime >= noonTime && currentTime < nightTime{
                navigationTitle = "Good Afternoon"
            }else{
                navigationTitle = "Good Night"
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```